# How to calculate spin correlation function via spin coherent state?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, coherent-states

I am following the Section 8.3.1 of Auerbach. I want to calculate spin correlation function via spin coherent state, i.e. the equation (8.28):
$$\begin{aligned}\left\langle\mathbf{S}_{m} \cdot \mathbf{S}_{n}\right\rangle=Z^{-1}\left(S+1\right)^2 \times \int \prod_{i} d \hat{\Omega}_{i}\left|\prod_{\langle i,j \rangle}(\frac{1-\hat{\Omega}_{i} \cdot \hat{\Omega}_{j}}{2})\right|^{2} \hat{\Omega}_{m} \cdot \hat{\Omega}_{n} \end{aligned}$$
where $\hat \Omega$ is the unit vector. I can obtain this equation. Then, Books recommends the iterative method ([ref](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.60.531) uses transfer matrix methods but not gives details). The final result is:
$$\left\langle\mathbf{S}_{m} \cdot \mathbf{S}_{n}\right\rangle=(-1)^n(S+1)^2\exp[-\ln(1+2/S)|m-n|]$$
I am wonder the details of this derivation, or the reference is also welcome!

Comment: Is this for a Heisenberg chain? (I'm not able to answer but giving your system might be a start.)

Comment: @jacob1729 Thanks for your comments! This is the spin correlation function of valence bond solids for 1D open chain, and actually can approximate to classical Heisenberg model (but not exactly equal). I don't gives this start point in original question since I am worried about misdirecting the focus of the question.